# Hive query CREATE TABLE WITH ORDER BY COLUMN stuck at 83%

Tags: hive

CREATE TABLE ordered_table

AS
SELECT name, epoc_time 
FROM reference_table

order by name, cast(epoc_time as bigint)

My reference_table has 1000000000 records.

This query works on smaller table but fails on this table at 83% with alerts on YARN and spark as below:

[Yarn alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAR32.png)

[Spark Thrift alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L684a.png)

Comment: `order by` implies total ordering, hence it got stuck at one reducer. At the same time `sort by` is much faster though it sort records just inside each reducer. You can always use `partition by` to distribute your records among reducers the way you need.

Comment: Try with Spark with RangePartitioning. Also why store sorted? Should query sorted (in general), more flexible.